# How to check if password satisfies devise validation requirements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my rails project I need to show certain error only if entered password satisfies devise validation requirements. Is there anything I can use for this?

`valid_password?` is not applicable here, since it only shows if entered password equals the one in DB.

Answer (score 2):

Devise only validates user password length, therefore I think `Devise.password_length.include?(user[:password].length)` would be enough.